# .htaccess not working on xampp Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, xampp, server

I have difficulties making my .htacces work on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I know it is a hidden file and all; I've searched everywhere and people seem to have the same problem. I've made a virtual host on my machine and all. Can someone please help me ?

```
ErrorDocument 404 /pages/error.php?code=404
ErrorDocument 403 /pages/error.php?code=403
```

Comment: My license for my crystal ball has expired. What are the problems you are facing? What do the logs say?

Comment: It works when I upload it on a server but doesn't work on localhost ! @Sumurai8

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem description. Do you get a white page? Do you get the default 404? Do you suddenly see pink unicorns? Does your computer spontaneously catch fire? Do you get a different error instead? **What is in the logs regarding this?**

Comment: Lol, i get default pages

Comment: What is your `DocumentRoot` set to? Is `<documentroot>/pages/error.php` an actual page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the following things are true:

- You need to check what `DocumentRoot` is set to. When an url beginning with a slash is detected, it will try to load that file relative to the document root. ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument)) The file `<documentroot>/pages/error.php` must thus exist.
- You need to make sure that .htaccess files are allowed by the main Apache configuration. The easiest way to test this is by entering garbage into your .htaccess file, saving it and reloading a page. You'll get an internal server error if Apache reads the .htaccess file. Otherwise the page loads as expected. To enable .htaccess files, the `AllowOverride` directive must allow something (see next bullet point). Additionally, check in httpd.conf if `AccessFileName` is set to something different than .htaccess. Change it as necessary, then **RESTART APACHE**. ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#accessfilename))
- For `ErrorDocument`, `AllowOverride` must be at least set to `FileInfo`. See [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride). Go to your main config file (httpd.conf), probably `apache/Apachex.y.z/conf/httpd.conf`. Search for the `<Directory ...>` block that corresponds to your http root, and look around if it contains an `AllowOverride` directive. Add `FileInfo` as one of the arguments, save the file and **RESTART APACHE**.